# First integral of Lanchester's model

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x = \alpha x - ay \\
\dot y = -b x + \beta y
\end{cases}
$$
Is there exist the first integral, if it is exist, what is it?

I already knows that:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x = - ay \\
\dot y = -b x
\end{cases}
$$
Has first integral:
$$I = bx^2 - ay^2 \Rightarrow \cfrac{dI}{dt} = 0$$
But this knowledge does not help with general problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assume
$$
I(x,y)=ex^2+fy^2+gxy.\;\;\;(1)
$$
Take the derivative wrt to time
$$
\frac{dI}{dt}=2ex(\alpha x-ay)+2fy(-bx+\beta y)
+x(-bx+\beta y)+y (\alpha x-ay).
$$
Collect the terms in $x^2$, $y^2$, and $xy$. Set each of the three coefficients to zero and you find the following system for $(e,f,g)^T$:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2\alpha&0&-b\\
0&2\beta&-a\\
-2a&-2b&\alpha+\beta
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
e\\f\\g
\end{array}
\right)=\vec{0}.\;\;\;(2)
$$
The system above has a nontrivial solution if the matrix (which I will call "$A$") is singular. The determinant is given by
$$
\det(A)=4(\alpha+\beta)(\alpha\beta-ab).
$$
Thus, (1) defines a nonzero first integral if
$$
\alpha=-\beta\text{ or } \alpha\beta=ab,
$$
and if $(e,f,g)^T$ is a nontrivial solution to the system (2).

Comment: What led you to the ansatz for (1)?

Comment: @Sal You can generalize Matvei's "simple" system by doing a linear change of variables in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you do so, the "simple" first integral stays quadratic except that the coefficients will change and there will be a term in $xy$. If I were Matvei, and that was important to me, I would try a cubic first integral also: $ex^3+fy^3+gx^2y+hxy^2$. It is easy to do with something like Mathematica. Perhaps somebody has done this before but I could not find it.